# How to convert List<Comparable<?>> to List<Comparable<Object>> in Java?

Tags: java, generics

Well, this will be a very lame question, but ... how to convert `List<Comparable<?>>` to `List<Comparable<Object>>` and backwards? Is there any nicer way than this?

```
private List<Comparable<Object>> convertFromGeneric(List<Comparable<?>> list) {
    List<Comparable<Object>> output = new ArrayList<Comparable<Object>>();
    for(Comparable<?> el : list) {
        output.add((Comparable<Object>) el);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to write my own backend part for SWT Table, because someone must be mad when he was developing this...

Comment: That isn't safe; someone can call `compareTo()` and pass an object of the wrong type.  Once you're resorting to unsafe generic casts, you can just cast the list.

Comment: What _exactly_ are you trying to do with this?

Comment: I was doing very messy thing! I used completely different solution and now I don't need to do this, and code is much faster and nicer.. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

The two types `List<Comparable<Object>>` and `List<Comparable<?>>` are not equivalent. The first is specifically a list of things that can be compared with `Object`s, while the second is a list of things that can each be compared to some mystery type you don't know.

This distinction is subtle but important: if I retrieve a `Comparable<Object>` from the list I can call `compareTo("myString")` on it, since a `String` is an `Object`; but if I have a `Comparable<?>` I can't call its `compareTo` method at all since for all I know it only compares integers, or floats, or `PeanutButterSandwich` instances. The upside is that the person who produced a `List<Comparable<?>>` could add a `Comparable<Integer>` and a `Comparable<String>` and a `Comparable<PeanutButterSandwich>` to a `List<Comparable<?>>`, but not to a `List<Comparable<Object>>`.

The way to resolve the problem depends on what you want to do with the list. I suspect you want to extract a `Comparable` from the list and compare it to an arbitrary `Object`. If that's what you want, then you need to change the method that receives the list so that its signature only accepts a `List<Comparable<Object>>` and presumably modify whatever other code produced that list in the first place so that it has the right type available.

If the caller was really giving you a `List<Comparable<PeanutButterSandwich>>` you'll have a problem; but it's a fundamental logic bug in your program. Trying to compare a random `Object` to a `PeanutButterSandwich` which is a plain old bug, and the fact that generics are being difficult here is a symptom of them doing their job correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way (you did not define nice):

`List<Comparable<?>>` to `List<Comparable<Object>>`:

```
(List<Comparable<Object>>)((List)list)
```

PS: I TESTED IT.

---

(edit by MightyPork ↓)

Here's a sample code proving that it works:

```
List<Comparable<?>> list = new ArrayList<Comparable<?>>();

// due to auto-boxing, those will turn into String, Integer and Boolean,
// all implementing Comparable
list.add("dfg");
list.add(1);
list.add(true);

List<Comparable<Object>> foo = (List<Comparable<Object>>)((List)list);

System.out.println(foo.get(0)); // this works
```

Comment: You only need one cast.

Comment: If you mean only with this cast `((List)list)` than yes, you can. But that would mean another warning later...

Comment: @MightyPork I tested it, so you are also welcome to test it too.

Comment: Okay so it does indeed work, but only because you first cast it to `List`. I wouldn't recommend this practice, but I am removing my downvote as this is a valid answer.

Comment: BTW: if you cast to `List<?>` rather than `List` you avoid a raw-types warning (though you still get the unchecked-cast warning).

Comment: I added a piece of code proving that it works, thought it'd be shame to just delete it. Remove it if you don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way generics works (type erasure), there really is no safe way to do this. You don't have any guarantees at runtime on what `?` really is.

What you *can* try is quantifying the `?` type. For example, you can try changing the type to `List<Comparable<? extends Object>>` instead.

Comment: `? extends Object` is the same as `?`.

Comment: NB: Type erasure has nothing to do with it. The cast is just plain unsound in general.

Comment: @SLaks yes, there's no real benefit of doing this. It's just syntactic sugar, IMO.